# Is it possible to ignore an output param of a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql, stored-procedures

How can I ignore an output parameter of a stored procedure? I'm calling the procedure from another procedure, e.g.:

```
DECLARE @param1 integer

EXEC mystoredprocedure 
    @in_param_1, 
    @in_param2_, 
    @param1 OUTPUT, 
    -- what do I type here to ignore the second output param??
```

I'm using T-SQL (MS SQL 2005).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can just use NULL as the last parameter, and it should work fine - as long as that parameter isn't expected for input logic in the proc as well.

In your case, you'd call the proc as

```
exec mystoredproc @in_param_1, @in_param2_, @param1 OUTPUT, null
```

Here's another example that for the same scenario...

```
create proc MyTempProc
    (@one int,
    @two int out,
    @three int out)
AS
begin

    set @two = 2
    set @three = 3

    select @one as One

end
go

declare @p1 int,
        @p2 int

set     @p1 = 1

exec MyTempProc @p1, @p2 out, null 

print @p1
print @p2
```

Answer (score 4):

The output parameter has to have a default in order for you to not pass it. See below

```
create proc x (@in int = null, @out int = null OUTPUT)
as 
Begin
    Select @in
End

exec x 1
```

**EDIT**

To clarify a little, the error is being returned because the stored procedure that is being called has a parameter defined (in this case @param1), for which no default is defined. (i.e. @param1 int rather than @param int = -1) In the case where neither a parameter or default is specified for a defined parameter of a stored procedure when calling the stored procedure an error will occur. The same thing would happen if you tired to omit an input parameter that does not have a default specified.

Comment: Really,  the sp *needs* to have an output?  That doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: Maybe that would be better stated as attempting to execute a stored procedure without specifying a value for a parameter that does not have a default results in an error, regardless of the direction of the parameter.

Comment: @MrGrieves: It may make sense, IMO. Of course a procedure may do whatever it does regardless, but it may make no sense to do it. For example, the procedure may have no other result than the output parameter, i.e. it doesn't change any state, just calculate something. (I know, a table-valued function might be more appropriate for this, and of course a scalar one if the result IS a scalar. Still...)

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably have to just ignore the OUTPUT param yourself by just not doing anything with the value. It's not like the overhead of that variable is an issue or anything. The only issue here is that your code will be a little bit uglier. So slap a comment on there explaining that the OUTPUT param isn't being used and everything should be alright.

Answer (score 0):

If the SP you're calling expects a parameter to be passed, you have to have one there. Even if you disregard the output of it, it is part of the structure of the SP.

Think of parameters as a "Data Contract". If they're not defaulted, they're required. Even if the values are disregarded.

Forcing you to declare a dummy value you'll never read is the cost of calling that stored proc that may be used by something that DOES need to utilize the value of the output parameter.